# bash: zcat vs. cat discrepancy for concatenating .gz files

Tags: bash

Here I've got a problem with my shell script. In my data analysis pipeline, I need to concatenate multiple gzipped files priore downstream analysis. These gzipped files come in pairs, so I need to concatenate all pair1 together and all pair2 together. My script for this looks like this:

```
for f in "${pair1_fqs[@]}"; do
    zcat "${f//\"/}" >> "$sampleID"_cat1.fq
done

for f in "${pair2_fqs[@]}"; do
    zcat "${f//\"/}" >> "$sampleID"_cat2.fq
done
```

the problem is zcat and cat returns different results:

```
zcat myfile.gz | wc -l
75896232
cat myfile.gz| wc -l
82322094
```

I was wondering if anyone here knows what could be the reason for this discrepancy!

Comment: If it is a zipped file, using `cat` against it does not have sense: just use `zcat`. Doing `cat` to a zipped file will probably show strange elements. Do the test with `seq 10 > hello` and then `cat hello.gz` and `zcat hello.gz`.

Comment: I can see the difference for human eye, but does this also differ for computer?

Comment: `gzip`ed files should be much smaller than plain, uncompressed files.  `zcat` decompressed the file so the result will be larger than with `cat` which does not decompress anything and so you're getting the raw compressed data.

Comment: `wc -l` doesn't show you file size; it shows you the number of *lines* in a file, which really means the number of linefeed characters (ASCII 10). Every byte with value 10 in a compressed file will be interpreted as a new line by `wc`, even though they aren't intended to be treated as ASCII characters.

Comment: Hmmm, this ASCII point make sense! As you noted I only care about the number of lines not the file size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`zcat` will uncompress first then pipe `wc -l`  will counts the lines.

`cat` will just pass the data read from the file then pipe to `wc -l`  will counts the lines.

Thats why you see different results, try `cat` on the compressed file, you will see gibberish.

Now try `zcat` on the compressed file, You will see your data.